# Getting error 'UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Trying to implement a slide out menu in one of my apps. When a user presses an option in the side menu it takes them to another view.

Was working find with the defaults that came in the example of the slide out menu I am using, but when I have my own in it is throwing up an error.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];



    NSLog(@"Row preseed%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"section preseed%ld", (long)indexPath.section);


    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        QuickGlanceViewController *homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];
        navigationController.viewControllers = @[homeViewController];
    }



    self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;
    [self.frostedViewController hideMenuViewController];
}
```

And here is the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UINavigationControllers
>   are not allowed in a navigation controller!'

Anyone have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: It looks like `QuickGlanceViewController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController` have a look at your nib layout in the storyboard.

Comment: So it is. What is the implications of this?

Comment: You'd have 2 navigation bars on your screen - don't know if you want that!

Comment: Amazing, thanks man, sorted now.

Comment: I'll claim that as an answer :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `QuickGlanceViewController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController` have a look at your nib layout in the storyboard.
You can't have a `UINavigationController` inside of another `UINavigationController`.